# "Множественное наследование" c#

Tags: c#, наследование

Есть иерархия классов, появилась ситуация в которой не могу придумать нормального решения. (стрелками показано наследование, красным цветом - желаемое, но невозможное )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Классы **U**, **S**, **A**, **W** используют одну и ту же реализацию функции **F**

А классы **SAI**, **AAI**, **WAI** другую, но общую между собой. Именно это и не получается реализовать так как нет возможности создать дополнительный класс **AI** реализовать в нем **F**  и тогда наследоваться от него. Получается что придется просто копировать реализацию  **F** для **SAI**, **AAI**, **WAI**, что есть плохо.

Какой есть способ красиво решить эту проблему??

Спасибо!

Comment: вынести функцию F в отдельный класс и вкидывать его через DI?

Comment: возможно какая-нибудь [стратегия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_\(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F\)) подойдет

Comment: AI нельзя воткнуть между U и S,A,W? Тогда было бы вполне то что надо.

Comment: @Monk, нет F реализовано  в  U, SAW - просто надстройки над U которые нужно перенести в SAW AI. но при этом переопределить реализацию F, и там будут другие надстройки(общие) для SAW AI, что тоже проблематично. Наверно придется менять структуру кода...

Answer (score 2):

Множественное наследование от нескольких классов невозможно. Используйте интерфейс `IFunctionF` и два вспомогательных класса `F1` и `F2`, каждый из которых имеет свою реализацию `IFunctionF`. И далее от `F1` и `F2` наследуйте ваши семейства `U,A,S,W` от `F1` и `SAI, AAI, WAI` от `F2`.

```
 public interface F
    {
       int F();

    }
    class F1:F
    {
        public virtual int F()
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    class F2 : F
    {
        public virtual int F()
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    class S : F1
    {
        void a()
        {
            F();
        }
    }

    class AAI : F2
    {
        void a()
        {
            F();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это я и пытаюсь решить. Я не хочу копировать 100500 раз одинаковою реализацию

Comment: Но тогда не получится реализовать наследование как на картинке в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

C# Extension methods (методы расширения) возможно помогут вам с переиспользованием кода (но, не факт, т.к. вы не сможете использовать приватные члены классов).

Пример:

```
Interface IFoo {}

public static class IFooExtensions
{
    public static int F(this IFoo foo)
    {
     //....
    }
}

//...........
int value = (myObj as IFoo).F();
```